# How to remove special characters from the return values of fetch_object in php

Tags: php

I have a challenge in overcoming from special characters in my MySQL DB.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM my table");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$parameter);
$stmt->execute();
            
$result = $stmt->get_result();
                    
$resultArray=array();
            
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    //echo json_encode($row); **This statement always returning right data.**
    array_push($resultArray,$row);
}

echo json_encode($resultArray); //This statement returns nothing when any of the data have special characters
```

How can i overcome this? Is there a way to escape special from the return values of $row?

The return of the $row is below object

```
[{"ID":13,"ClassName":"4,5","QuestionName":"Who discovered telephone?","Option1":"Albert - Einstein","Option2":"Newton","Option3":"Alexander Grahambell","Option4":"Thomas Alva Edison","RightOption":3,"Duration":60,"IsRegionSpecific":0,"VideoReference":"","Explanation":""}]
```

Comment: It all depends on the contents of `$resultArray`, which are not shown here. So one can only guess that maybe use of `options` as stated [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) might change things.

Comment: @Luuk added the object of the response i am getting from the DB. How can i apply to all such rows of data.

Comment: You need to define what are special characters. In what context? What happens at the moment? Do you get garbled out output? Do you get JSON error?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me array_map('utf8_encode', $row)

```
            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$myparam);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    
            $resultArray=array();
            
            while($row = $result->fetch_array())
            {
                **$row = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);**
                array_push($resultArray,$row);
            }

            echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: Do you know what `utf8_encode` does? Why are you using this function?